# How can I use the New-Object cmdlet in a PowerShell script when my constructor takes in a large array of bytes?

Tags: arrays, .net, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am writing a PowerShell function/script (using the version that ships with Windows 10, which I believe is 5.0) to take in a GZip compressed Base64 string and decompress it, and then decode it under the assumption the original uncompressed/decoded string was Unicode encoded.

I am trying to instantiate a new object instance of type MemoryStream using [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte())) and the New-Object cmdlet. It takes one parameter, which is an array of bytes.

PowerShell is unable to find a valid overload that accepts the array of bytes I am trying to pass as the constructor's parameter. I believe the issue is due to the array's relatively large length. Please see my code below:

```
Function DecompressString()
{
    param([parameter(Mandatory)][string]$TextToDecompress)
    
    try
    {
        $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($TextToDecompress)

        $srcStreamParameters = @{
            TypeName = 'System.IO.MemoryStream'
            ArgumentList = ([byte[]]$bytes)
        }

        $srcStream = New-Object @srcStreamParameters
        $dstStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.MemoryStream
        
        $gzipParameters = @{
            TypeName = 'System.IO.Compression.GZipStream'
            ArgumentList = ([System.IO.Stream]$srcStream, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        }
        
        $gzip = New-Object @gzipParameters
        $gzip.CopyTo($dstStream)
        $output = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($dstStream.ToArray())
        Write-Output $output
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($gzip -ne $null) { $gzip.Dispose() }
        if ($srcStream -ne $null) { $srcStream.Dispose() }
        if ($dstStream -ne $null) { $dstStream.Dispose() }
    }
}

DecompressString
$ExitPrompt = Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to Exit'
```

The error message I get is: `Cannot find an overload for "MemoryStream" and the argument count: "1764".`

Can anyone please clarify how I can get the script interpreter to use the constructor correctly with a large byte array?

Comment: It's trying to pass each element of `$bytes`, which apparently is of length 1764, as a separate argument to a `MemoryStream` constructor but no such overload exists.  You need to wrap `$bytes` in an array like this: `,([byte[]]$bytes)` (note the leading comma).

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Thank you! That worked! Can you please remove your comment and add it as an answer, so I can upvote and accept it? Thanks again!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you use `$srcStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new([byte[]]$bytes)` instead?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes it does!

Comment: If this script is running on PS5.1+, I would recommend you to change all those `New-Object` statements for `[typename]::new(..)`. Faster and more efficient.

Comment: PowerShell automatically unwind arrays in many cases. Workaround with unary comma operator does the trick when you want to pass the array as a single thing. But reader might easily miss this operator, thus Lance used comment "(note the leading comma)". To make the intent more clear, in my scripts I use "Write-Output -NoEnumerate" instead of comma. i.e. `Write-Output @(1,2,3) -NoEnumerate | ForEach-Object { "recieved: $_" }` instead of `,@(1,2,3) | ForEach-Object { "recieved: $_" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would share an answer to this question which I found very interesting, solution to the error has already been provided by [Lance U. Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/lance-u-matthews) in his helpful comment, by adding the [unary operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-) before the `$bytes` assigned to the `ArgumentList` of [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object), by doing so, the `$bytes` are passed as a single argument (*array of bytes*) and not as individual elements to the constructor of [`System.IO.MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-6.0):

```bash
$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($compressedString)
$srcStreamParameters = @{
    TypeName     = 'System.IO.MemoryStream'
    ArgumentList = , $bytes
}

$srcStream = New-Object @srcStreamParameters
```

[Beginning in **PowerShell 5.0**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#new-method-for-types) and going forward, you can construct your memory stream with the following syntax, which is more efficient and straight forward:

```bash
$srcStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($bytes)
```

As for the functions (**Compress** & **Expand**), I would like to share my take on these cool functions.

- Required [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.2) and [`ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.argumentcompleterattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) for `-Encoding` Parameter.

```bash
using namespace System.Text
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.IO.Compression
using namespace System.Collections
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression

class EncodingCompleter : IArgumentCompleter {
    [IEnumerable[CompletionResult]] CompleteArgument (
        [string] $commandName,
        [string] $parameterName,
        [string] $wordToComplete,
        [CommandAst] $commandAst,
        [IDictionary] $fakeBoundParameters
    ) {
        [CompletionResult[]] $arguments = foreach($enc in [Encoding]::GetEncodings().Name) {
            if($enc.StartsWith($wordToComplete)) {
                [CompletionResult]::new($enc)
            }
        }
        return $arguments
    }
}
```

- Compression from ***string*** to ***Base64 GZip compressed string***:

```bash
function Compress-GzipString {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $String,

        [Parameter()]
        [ArgumentCompleter([EncodingCompleter])]
        [string] $Encoding = 'utf-8',

        [Parameter()]
        [CompressionLevel] $CompressionLevel = 'Optimal'
    )

    try {
        $enc       = [Encoding]::GetEncoding($Encoding)
        $outStream = [MemoryStream]::new()
        $gzip      = [GZipStream]::new($outStream, [CompressionMode]::Compress, $CompressionLevel)
        $inStream  = [MemoryStream]::new($enc.GetBytes($string))
        $inStream.CopyTo($gzip)
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
    }
    finally {
        $gzip, $outStream, $inStream | ForEach-Object Dispose
    }

    try {
        [Convert]::ToBase64String($outStream.ToArray())
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
    }
}
```

- Expansion from ***Base64 GZip compressed string*** to ***string***:

```bash
function Expand-GzipString {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $String,

        [Parameter()]
        [ArgumentCompleter([EncodingCompleter])]
        [string] $Encoding = 'utf-8'
    )

    try {
        $enc       = [Encoding]::GetEncoding($Encoding)
        $bytes     = [Convert]::FromBase64String($String)
        $outStream = [MemoryStream]::new()
        $inStream  = [MemoryStream]::new($bytes)
        $gzip      = [GZipStream]::new($inStream, [CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        $gzip.CopyTo($outStream)
        $enc.GetString($outStream.ToArray())
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
    }
    finally {
        $gzip, $outStream, $inStream | ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}
```

And for the little ***Length*** comparison, querying the [Loripsum API](https://loripsum.net/):

```bash
$loremIp = Invoke-RestMethod loripsum.net/api/10/long
$compressedLoremIp = Compress-GzipString $loremIp

$loremIp, $compressedLoremIp | Select-Object Length

Length
------
  8353
  4940

(Expand-GzipString $compressedLoremIp) -eq $loremIp # => Should be True
```

These 2 functions as well as **Compression From File Path** and **Expansion from File Path** can be found on [this repo](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression).